# Is it possible to webpack a nodejs server.js app that also exports objects/modules for external import?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I really wouldn't ask this question, but I'm stuck in a situation where webpack is being used to bundle a server-side Express app, which is using `__non_webpack_require__` to import a module.js from an external file. The require works fine at runtime, but there are some imports/requires in the external module.js that need to import/require code that's in the main source base. A package.json `_moduleAliases` alias is used to home the require path. e.g. `const Logger = require('@/logging/Logger');` where @ is .

This works fine in a development build but I expect its because the source is accessible. When I do a webpack production bundling, the controller service function that calls `__non_webpack_require__` works fine (the external .js files are imported, but when imported the first line in one of them is `const Logger = require('@/logging/Logger');` which can't be required/found, because that module is in the server.bundle.js at this point.

I can try to work around this a couple of ways (that I can see):

1. Remove webpack entirely, be we use it to pull in various distribution dependencies, etc... It'll have to be replaced with a new script.
2. Move the related modules to their own external module, outside of the server.bundle.js, then require it separately. Basically the equivalent to a regular node_module.
3. Somehow have the server.bundle.js export these modules, while at the same time being a node type module, so an externally required (`__non_webpack_require__`) module can require/import something from server.bundle.js.

I know, I know. This is some inception type mess.

**Update**

Ok, in my webpack.config.js I added an extra config, separate from the original so it'll build the output asa library, and the app separately:

```
module.exports = (env, argv) => {
  return [
    {
      mode: 'production',
      target: "node",
      entry: "./exports.js",
      resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
      },
      module: {
        rules: [],
      },
      externals: [nodeExternals()],
      output: {
          path: path.join(dirname, '/dist'),
          filename: 'exports.bundle.js',
          libraryTarget: "umd"
      },

    },
    {
      entry: {
        ...
```

I created an `exports.js` in the main source that requires the modules I want to export and make available outside the main bundled app:

```
const config = require('@/config/config');
const Logger = require('@/logging/Logger');
export {
    config,
    Logger
}
```

This results in an `exports.bundle.js`. In the separate source that gets `__non_webpack_require__` from the main app, I import the exports (note this is test code because it's not all working perfectly):

```
console.log('initializing process...')
const { config } = require('@/exports.bundle');
console.log('config: ' + config)
console.log('config: ' + config.processFolder)

const { Logger } = require('@/exports.bundle');
console.log('Logger: ' + Logger)
const logger = new Logger();
```

Here's the logging post `__non_webpack_require__`:

```
 initializing process...
 config: [object Object]
 config: /app/process

 Logger: class E{constructor(){return E.instance||(E.instance=a.getLogger("App"),E.instance.info(`Logging to ${i}`)),E.instance}}

TypeError: Logger is not a constructor
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/process/process.js:1:242)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1004:32)
     at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:839:12)
     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:19)
     at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/process/workflowManager.js:1:754)
     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1180:10)
```

You can see `config` works, I can access member variables. It's an `Object`.

While `Logger` is a class description, that when I try to construct, `is not a constructor`.

I'm close. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your exports.js is mixing commonjs/esm. You shouldn't do that. Also you might want to check out webpack's [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/provide-plugin/).